# I can't access Samba share from Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, samba4

I have Ubuntu 16.04.1. I have Samba 4. Windows writes access denied. I can reach the shared folder, but I can't access. 
I also tried smbclient to login and that writes: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
My smb.conf file:

```
[megosztas]
path = /home/attila/Asztal/megosztas
available = yes
valid users = fel1
read only = no
browseable = yes
public = yes
writeable = yes
guest ok = yes
```

Comment: I tried smbclient to login, but that also failed. The output: Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Windows 6.1] Server=[Samba 4.3.11-Ubuntu] tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED

Comment: I solved this problem. I added the password before the user. I just used smbpasswd -a user command again, then it works. :)